# Apply media query unless there's a specific class or container

Tags: css

I have a number of media queries throughout the code that check for screen size, things like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
  ...some styles for smaller screens
}
@media screen and (min-width: 841px) {
  ...some styles for bigger screens
}
```

I want to apply the smaller screen styles in a bigger screen context if and only if the elements in question are within another container element.  My first attempt was to do this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
  ...some styles for smaller screens
}
@media screen and (min-width: 841px) {
  @container not my-container {
     ...some styles for bigger screens
  }
}
```

The idea is that since the bigger screen styles come after the smaller screen styles, the smaller screen styles will still be applied if within the container.  However this seems to negate the bigger screen styles regardless of the presence of the container and just didn't work.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW with modern HTML and available CSS a lot of media queries can simply be removed and/or incorporated into the CSS

Comment: Understood, unfortunately these media queries are used in many many places and it would be more work than I have time for to clean them all up.